# Remove All Change Data Capture

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

When trying to disable change data capture on a 2014 instance `EXEC sys.sp_cdc_disable_db`, I get the message:

The result is a message like this:

> Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of
>   BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1

From my analysis, there were numerous objects that were removed (one job, four tables, data in the tables related to the change data monitoring), that should not have been removed.  I don't see how any recovery at this point is possible.  I don't see how *else* to remove all change data capture, other than drop every object one-by-one and I'm not convinced that would work.

If this occurs ("corruption of this whole process"), is there an alternative way to remove it?

Comment: Can you check the owner of database ? Is it `sa` or some windows login .. ? Should be `sa`.  Also what service pack + CU are you running on ? See [this](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2009/02/01/sql-server-2008-change-data-capture-msg-22830-level-16-state-1.aspx)

Comment: It sounds like that error message might be a side-effect of some prior error.  Is there anything else reported by `sp_cdc_disable_db` ?

Comment: (at) Kin Yes sa is owner and the service pack on the 2014 instance is 2.
(at) MaxVernon That's the only error when attempting to disable.

Comment: does disabling cdc on just one table give you the error as well ?

Comment: @Kin I can't disable anything for a table because there are 0 capture instances and 0 records in `cdc.change_tables`.  In other words, CDC is enabled on this database, but it's showing that nothing is being monitored by it and I am unable to stop/remove it, unless there's another way (thus the question).